# How do I replace method addresses in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, aop

I'm replacing method addresses in C# desktop Apps by using this approach:

```
var destMethod = typeof(BaseViewModel).GetMethod("desc");
var srcMethod = typeof(BaseViewModel).GetMethod("src");
*((uint*)new IntPtr(((int*)destMethod.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2)).ToPointer()) = *((uint*)new IntPtr(((int*)srcMethod.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2)).ToPointer());
```

In desktop app after address is replaced and I call "dest" method:

```
var viewModel = new BaseViewModel();
viewModel.dest();
```

"src" method automatically handles this call.

But in Silverlight it doesn't work and when I try to call "dest" method then "src" method is not called.

Please advise if this approach can be also used for Silverlight and what should I change to make it works.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is *never* enough information. What exactly happens? What are you trying to achieve? ("replacing method addresses" isn't a very informative description)

Comment: Sorry for lack of info, I adjusted post. In Silverlight I can't replace method address in the same way as in desktop app.
In result I want to achieve runtime method replacing.

Comment: Well it's still not clear why you'd *want* to do this - it looks like you'd be better off using an interface that could have multiple implementations etc instead of monkeying around with the internals.

Comment: In my case this is not an option, I want to intercept method calls without changing current code.

Comment: I strongly suspect you're out of luck then. I generally regard Silverlight as a bit more of a "locked down" platform, so I'm not surprised you're having problems fiddling with the internals like this.